# whether menu will work in android3.1 for honey comb tablet?

Tags: android

I have created project in android2.3.3 using onCreateOptionsMenu whether it will work in android tablet?.there is no menu button in android tablet

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [oficial guides](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html) menu button will appear to left of main buttons in bottom action 
 bar.

Comment: If you set targetSdkVersion=11 or higher, then it will appear in the action bar.